# remove duplicate slides from owl-carousel-o angular

Tags: angular, owl-carousel

I want to remove the duplicate slides while move from one dot tot another. I declared the html code like below,

`<owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions" > <ng-template carouselSlide *ngFor="let slide of slides" [id]="slide.id"> <div (click)="openSlide(slide)"> <div>{{slide.Name}}</div> </div> </ng-template> </owl-carousel-o>`

`customOptions: OwlOptions ={
loop: true,
mouseDrag: false,
touchDrag: false,
pullDrag: false,
dots: true,
margin: 10,
//rewind: true,

```
  //navSpeed: 700,
  navText: ['', ''],
  //items: 4,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 0
    },
    400: {
      items: 1
    },
    740: {
      items: 4
    },
    940: {
      items: 4 
    }
  },
  nav: false
};
```

`

I tried loop: false but It was not working.

Can you help me to remove the duplicate slides when we move from dot to dot?

I want to re initialize the option when I am modifying. Can you help me to refresh the options also, please??